# Issue when inserting DateType Field with Symfony 3 Forms

Tags: php, mysql, symfony-forms, symfony

I searched a lot and can't find any in StackOverflow about my problem...

I have this structure: ( resumed )

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($vendedor)
            // ...
            ->add('datanascimento', DateType::class, [
                'label' =>'D.Nascimento',
                'attr'  =>['class'=>'input-sm'],
                'format'=>'d-M-yyyy',
                'years'=>range(1970, 2010)
            ])
            // ...
            ->getForm();
```

And i have this configs in my Entity:

```
//...

/**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dataNascimento", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $datanascimento;

//...

/**
     * Set datanascimento
     *
     * @param string $datanascimento
     *
     * @return CadPfPj
     */
    public function setDatanascimento($datanascimento)
    {
        $this->datanascimento = $datanascimento;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get datanascimento
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDatanascimento()
    {
        return $this->datanascimento;
    }
```

When i try insert an new register, i got this error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException
```

When i debug, and dump the object... I found this:

```
//...
-datanascimento: DateTime {#530 ▼
    +"date": "1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "America/Sao_Paulo"
  }
//...
```

My database was mySQL and the field type is datetime...
How can i configure symfony to stop send an array and send just the "date"?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `widget` [type of form entry](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#date-widget) – default is `choice`, but you need `text` or `single_text`.

```
        ->add('datanascimento', DateType::class, [
            'label'  =>'D.Nascimento',
            'widget' =>'single_text',         
            'attr'   =>['class'=>'input-sm'],
            'format' =>'d-M-yyyy',
            'years'  =>range(1970, 2010)
        ])
```